# Cant access property "createdAt" on Cloud Code Parse Framework

Tags: javascript, ios, arrays, parse-platform

I'm using Cloude Code to create a query a little more complex, but i cant access, the property that is automatically created by Parse "createdAt", 
heres my code :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("get_time", function(request, response)
{
    var query = new Parse.Query("Test");
    var today = new Date(); // gets today
    var thirdDaysAgo = new Date(today - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30); // gets 30 days ago
    var threeHoursAgo = new Date(today - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 1); // gets 3 hours ago

    query.greaterThan("createdAt", thirdDaysAgo);
    query.greaterThan("createdAt", threeHoursAgo);
    query.descending("createdAt");

    query.find({
    success: function(results) 
    {    
            if(results.length > 0)
            {
                var finalArray = [];
                for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
                { 
                    var dataCreated = results[i].get("createdAt");
                    finalArray.push(dataCreated);
                }
                response.success(finalArray);
            }
    },
    error: function() 
    {
      response.error("time lookup failed");
    }});
});
```

The finalArray, is filled only with null objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you can't use `greaterThan` twice on the same field, the last one is the only one that will stick.

Secondly you say that results is filled with null objects, so it is returning an array of results then?

Is it `results` that is full of nulls, or is it `finalArray`. You should be aware that `objectId`, `createdAt` and `modifiedAt` aren't available via `get("columnName")`, they are native properties so you have to use `results[i].createdAt` instead. That is why `finalArray` would be full of null values.